# using ant script to exceute a batch file

Tags: ant, batch-file, cruisecontrol

this is a batch file that i have. It is located in `C:\Work\6.70_Extensions\Lab Tools\` folder.

**ANT.BAT:**

```
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;.;c:\JavaMail\javamail-1.3\mail.jar;c:\JavaMail\javamail-1.3\mailapi.jar;c:\JavaMail\javamail-1.3\pop3.jar;c:\JavaMail\javamail-1.3\smtp.jar;c:\JavaMail\jaf-1.0.2\activation.jar
CALL "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\bin\vcvars32.bat"
@echo on

%ANT_HOME%\bin\ant -logger org.apache.tools.ant.listener.MailLogger -q -buildfile "Master Build.xml"
pause
```

along with `ant.bat`, i have a `Master Build.xml` file located inside the same folder.

When i double click on `ant.bat`, it will execute the Master Build.xml ant script properly.

However, whenever i try to use another application to open the batch file's absolute path, it always state that `Master Build.xml file does not exist!`

I tried to open the absolute path using both console application and another ANT Script(via Cruisecontrol framework) but both gives the same error. What is the error here?

for your information here is what ive done with `cruisecontrol`:

1. create `config.xml` (to set intervals for builds)
2. create `nightbuild.xml` (so that `config.xml` will go into it to perform required tasks)
3. `nightbuild.xml` will run several console applications to sort files, checkout files from version control etc
4. lastly, `nightbuild.xml` will execute `ant.bat` file to execute the build

These files, `config.xml` and `nightbuild.xml` are found in `C:\build`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute from a directory other than the one containing `Master Build.xml`, Ant will fail to find the build file, which it expects to be in the current working directory.

You could set an additional environment variable to specify the path to the build file, e.g.

```
%ANT_HOME%\bin\ant -buildfile "%MASTER_BUILD%\Master Build.xml"
```

If you set your variable to an absolute path (e.g. `C:\Work\6.70_Extensions\Lab Tools`) then it will always work. If you use a relative path (e.g. `.\Lab Tools`), then it will only work if executed from the relative root dir.

(BTW, life will probably be easier if you use buildfiles without spaces in their names, e.g. `master_build.xml` rather than `Master Build.xml`).